# freecodecamp tribute page error "5. When I click a .nav-link button in the nav element, I am taken to the corresponding section of the landing page.'"

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

When I test the code it detect there one of the likns of the navbar menu don'go to any section of the page as required in the conditions .Despite the warning, the page works okey.

I tried removing last anchor  with href="javascript:void(0);", warning disappears , but the "burguer menú" for small devices don't work.

```
<nav class="topnav"  id="nav-bar">
    <a  href="#header"  class="active nav-link">Home</a>
    <a  href="#img-div"  class="nav-link">Image</a>
    <a  href="#tribute-info">info</a>
    <a  class="nav-link"  href="#video">video</a>
    <a  class="nav-link"  href="#form">contact</a>
    <a  class="nav-link" href="#footer">footer</a>
    <a  href="javascript:void(0);"  class="icon nav-link" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i  class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</nav>
```

and javascript code:

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

I expect fix the warning , "The .nav-link with href="javascript:void(0);" is not linked to a corresponding element on the page : expected null to not equal null" , but really it's logicat that it displays. How can I "cheat" the Test whithout loosing functionality?